# Is it possible to have a Web API route of the form /api/{id}-{type}.png?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

Currently I have this route defined in my Web API config:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetImage",
            routeTemplate: "api/{agency}-{energytype}.png",
            defaults: new { controller = "Values",
                            agency = "arb",
                            energytype = "energy" }
            );
```

I have this action in my controller which is the intended target (nothing in here yet just seeing if I can get there)

```
   public string Get(string agency, string energyType)
    {
        return "Agency: " + agency + "    Energy Type: " + energyType;
    }
```

I want it to appear to the end user that they are just linking to an image. The fact that it's a Web API response should be transparent. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Using extensions in routes needs UriPathExtensionMapping

Comment: From what I've read you need something like

`config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new UriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json"));`

I don't see a formatter for a PNG though. Does this mean I need to write a custom formatter?